# Can I use the number of particles rather than concentration in biological differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, biology

(This question is not specific to biology, but I was just wondering about a common way that people view differential equations in biology.)

Some simple biological differential equations take the form $ \frac{dx}{dt}=-cx$, where the solution is $ x=x_0e^{-ct}$, $x_0$ being an initial concentration of particles.

I usually see problems treat $x$ as a concentration of particles, but is there any particular reason why we can't treat $x$ as a number of particles? Some of my friends said there may be a problem if we treat $x$ as a number of particles, but I couldn't understand their explanation.

Comment: In the abstract, there is no difference, if all the constants get translated accordingly. Practically, the numerical solvers have built-in heuristics that may not scale well if the scale of some components gets excessively large or small. Concentrations tend to fall more easily into the working range. Also, if you apply non-dimensionalization (for the named reasons of being friendly to your solver), you usually end up with something resembling a concentration, so you would avoid to circle back when staying with the concentration model from the start.